# Comparar valor de un campo preformateado con sha1 en eloquent orm

Tags: php, eloquent, orm

estoy enviando una URL al correo de un usuario que debe recibirla asi:

http://dominio/registro/23

Donde el 23 es el id de un registro de una tabla, que por efectos prácticos no es deseado en este momento, así que convierto el 23 con sha1() una cadena .. de manera que la  URL finalmente enviada queda aproximadamente así.

```
http://dominio/registro/fjhjsdfsd9fsdfn4kw8944mfg9rtgmerer
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, el asunto es que ya de regreso al sistema para validar esa url  necesito contrastarla con el ID original (23).

Como este es un valor que viene desde un ambiente externo no quisiera pasar la evaluación a eloquent como una consulta RAW de MySQL tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE sha1(id) = "fjhjsdfsd9fsdfn4kw8944mfg9rtgmerer"
```

Pero no logro hacer que me funcione algo así en eloquent:

```
$model = ClaseX::where(sha1("id"),"fjhjsdfs...gmerer")->first();
```

Pues obviamente sha1("id") aparentemente calcula el valor pero para la cadena "id" y no para el campo id de la tabla.

Alguna idea para validar el ID que se envía al correo sin tener que mostrarlo explícitamente y no pasar una consulta RAW a Eloquent ???

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se puede apreciar el id Hasheado te llega como un parámetro de la URL, entonces:

Suponiendo que el método al que te llega este request se llama store

```
public function store($idHaseado){
    $model = ClaseX::where(DB::raw('sha1("id")'),$idHaseado)->first();
}
```